# Would Infel has disappeared if she and Nenesha succeeded?

Tags: ar-tonelico

At the end of *Ar Tonelico II - Melody of Metafalica* when Luca and Cloche are singing *EXEC_with.METHOD_METAFALICA/.* Frelia is warning Infel that if Luca and Cloche are successful Infel will disappear because of what will happen to the Infel Pira, all the while Infel is saying she knows she's going to disappear because she designed Infel Pira.

But i am wondering, would Infel had disappeared when she and Nenesha tried to create Metafalica 400 year ago and succeeded? does this mean Metafalica was doomed to fail back then because it would require someone to sacrifice their life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reserching in the [EXA.PICO Wikia](http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/Infel) about Infel, it seems thatn in the chance the Song was executed properly, no one would have died. As long as Infel's calculations were correct.
Infel developed METHOD_METAFALICA/. to patch the EXEC_METAFALICA/. song, which had requirements to strong, and ended up killing any Revaitail who sang it.

So, is is likely Metafalica could have worked back then, if Infel had not closed of her heart and caused the song to fail.

The reason Infel will die if Luca and Cloche succesfully sing METHOD_METFALICA/. is because she is now a sublimated consciousness living in the Infel Phira server, and the transmigration of Infel Phira would defragment the server's memory and delete her data.

Comment: Also, Infel wasn't at fault for the failure of her Metafalica attempt, but the IPDs that were supposed to sing with her and Nenesha: they betrayed her at the most crucial moment because they didn't like that Infel was creating Metafalica for Nenesha and for her research instead of for them.